# Присоединительные конструкции с "например"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис

*При использовании традиционной системы управления производственным предприятием большинство сопутствующих «амортизационных» расходов перекладываются на покупателя: они либо включены в стоимость готовой продукции, либо будут возникать впоследствии, например при замене или ремонте изделия.*

Является ли здесь "например при замене или ремонте изделия" присоединительным оборотом? И соответственно правильно ли не поставлена запятая после "например"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Текст оформлен правильно, вводное слово "например" выступает в роли присоединительного союза для уточняющего оборота.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 2):

Возможны оба варианта.

Без вводного слова: *Они либо включены в стоимость готовой продукции, либо будут возникать впоследствии при замене или ремонте изделия*. Обособленного оборота нет.

Добавляем вводное слово: *Они либо включены в стоимость готовой продукции, либо будут возникать впоследствии, например, при замене или ремонте изделия*.

Но вводное слово САМО МОЖЕТ СОЗДАВАТЬ ОБОСОБЛЕННЫЙ ОБОРОТ: *Они либо включены в стоимость готовой продукции, либо будут возникать впоследствии, например при замене или ремонте изделия*.

Comment: Не знаю такого явления, как создание вводным словом обособленного оборота.Не могли бы Вы дать ссылку? Известно только то, что вводное слово может начинать собой обособленный оборот и выделяется запятой вместе со всем оборотом

Comment: Это правило из Словаря вводных слов. Цитирую: Нередко вводное слово, относящееся к тому или иному члену предложения, само создает обособленный оборот там, где его, не будь здесь вводного слова, не было бы. "В одну ночь, должно быть из озорства, списком был оклеен фасад городской думы" (А.Фадеев). Опустим вводное
слово: "В одну ночь из озорства списком был оклеен фасад городской думы" - получилось обстоятельство причины, обособление которого факультативно. Благодаря вводному слову оно становится обособленным оборотом.