# Например(,) чтобы достать молоток

Tags: запятые

Как правильно?

1. Тебе надо быть большим, то есть вырости, и это тебе пригодится – точно пригодится, например, чтобы достать молоток.
2. Тебе надо быть большим, то есть вырости, и это тебе пригодится – точно пригодится, например чтобы достать молоток.

Comment: Мне кажется, что запятая нужна, т. к. можно опустить без потери смысла

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39602/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Тебе надо быть большим, то есть вырасти, и это тебе пригодится – точно пригодится, **например чтобы достать молоток.***

Здесь нужно применить правило **[Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137), пункт 5**

5. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят слова особенно, в частности, то есть, а именно, **например**, а также, а просто и т. п. с присоединительным значением, то запятая после этих слов не ставится: На всякий случай имейте при себе удостоверение личности, например когда будете получать деньги по почтовому переводу.

**[Также](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)**  В роли присоединительной конструкции может выступать и придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения: Необходимы были всякие меры предосторожности, особенно если приходилось идти ночью; В некоторых условиях обстановки, и в частности когда войска на отдыхе, кухни располагаются на грунте.

Comment: А если перед союзом вводное слово? Пример: *Он для чего-то взял молоток, возможно(,) чтобы забить-таки висячий веки вечные гвоздь.*

Comment: Вводное слово обособляется по пункту 7 правила Розенталя.  А слово "например" у него в значении присоединительного союза, а не вводного слова.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137  Он для чего-то взял молоток, возможно, чтобы забить-таки висячий веки вечные гвоздь.

Comment: А если так. Версия как пояснение:  Он для чего-то взял молоток, возможно,  для того, чтобы забить-таки висячий веки вечные гвоздь.  

Версия как присоединение:  Ведь для чего-то он взял молоток,  (это) возможно для того,  чтобы забить-таки висячий веки вечные гвоздь.